# Emu E6400 Ultra crosstalk/left and right channels bleeding into each other

Tags: hardware, sampler

when resampling, I get crosstalk/left and right channels bleeding into each other during auditioning the sounds when the "monitor on" is selected on the emu...Especially when you crank up the ADC gain, to saturate the sound left and right channels bleeding into each other...Even if you have a mono input on the left channel, when you crank up ADC gain when resampling, you can hear little of the left channel on the right channel, Is this normal with emu hardware samplers ? Is this like analog desk crosstalk where channels bleed into each other...to exactly recreate the process: have only one channel connected to your emu, eg. left channel, then when resampling the left channel with monitor on option checked and being on stereo resample mode, crank up the ADC gain you should be hearing the left channel on the right speakers, it even shows on the gain display...Is this like analog desk kinda crosstalk/channel bleed ? and do you get the same results on your emu hardware sampler, too...I am just trying to rule out the hardware failure option...If anybody else experiencing this can you share your thoughts, much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

Get it fixed, if it's a problem (I don't know if it's "normal" with the EMU E6400, but crosstalk surely can be and is avoided by electrical design, unless it happens because e.g. the internals have gathered dirt over time).

Comment: I have just confirmed with another emu user, he's got it, too. Sounds like a design flaw, but then again crosstalk might sometimes be desirable thing...I hope some other people reply to confirm this channel bleed issue with their emu hardware sampler...